# Read-only mutableStateListOf

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

In Jetpack Compose, if I have a `MutableState` variable, I can expose it's State as **"read-only"** value to other classes as `State<String>`, just like:

```
private val _title = mutableStateOf("abc")
val title: State<String> = _title
```

Is there a way to do this with `SnapshotStateList<>` too? How would I do this for example with:

```
private val _titles = mutableStateListOf<String>(...)
val titles: ??? = _titles
```

I know that I could work around this by just using `MutableState<List<String>>`, but I'd have to provide a whole new list every time I would want to add/remove items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutableStateListOf` create an object of `SnapshotStateList`, which is subclass of `MutableList`, so you can use `List`:

```
val titles: List<String> = _titles
```

Also with `mutableStateOf` you can use a single variable with delegation:

```
var title by mutableStateOf("abc")
    private set
```

Comment: Oh wow, so if I use the "immutable List" `titles` in a composable, compose would know there's a State-object behind that to observe and still recomposes when `_titles` changes?

Comment: @DominikSeemayr this doesn't change actual type of `_titles`, that's why state object works as expected.