# Test Android Compose State values

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-jetpack-compose

I've implemented Android view model which exposes Compose `State<T>` instance. For instance, view model implementation:

```
class MyViewModel<S> {
    private val _viewState: MutableState<S> = mutableStateOf(initialState)
    val viewState: State<S> = _viewState
    ...
    protected fun setState(newState: S) {
        _viewState.value = newState
    }
}
```

I'd like to test in unit tests what values/state it will get set. Just a brief example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
class MyViewModelTest {
    @Test
    fun `when view model initialized then should emit initial state first`() {
        val viewModel = MyViewModel()
        assertEquals(InitialState(), viewModel.viewState.value)
    }

    @Test
    fun `when view model interacted then should emit result state`() {
        val viewModel = MyViewModel()
        val expectedState = NewState()

        viewModel.setState(expectedState)

        assertEquals(expectedState, viewModel.viewState.value)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to test `State<T>`? How do you guys unit test compose states values if you store them in view model side?

Comment: what's wrong with your code? by the way, you can use a short version of state declaration with `private set`, as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71147730/3585796)

Comment: Hi @PhilipDukhov. `assertEquals(expectedState, viewModel.viewState.value)` will always get just first value which is `initialState`. This concept does't observe all values.

Comment: maybe [`snapshotFlow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#snapshotFlow(kotlin.Function0)) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

For my specific use case, I'm using coroutines and unidirectional data flow, but exposing state via `mutableStateOf`. Was looking to Unit Test initial state + effect of events as is your case.

##### View Model:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(
  // For injecting test dispatcher
  private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : ViewModel() {

  // State exposed via delegate
  var state by mutableStateOf(State.Show())
    private set

  fun onEvent(event: Event) {
    when (event) {
      is Event.Greet -> greet(event)
      else -> TODO("Other Stuff")
    }
  }

  private fun greet(greet: Event.Greet) {
    viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
      // Do some, ya know, API stuff!
      state = State.Show("Hello ${greet.name}")
    }
  }
}
```

`state` is exposed via delegate, with a private setter. The initial value would be `Show("Hello")`. We can also set updates directly with the imports:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

The injection of the dispatcher is essential for controlling the progression.

##### States & Events, for completeness

```kotlin
// Encapsulates possible states
sealed class State {

  // Data class calculates equality from the constructor
  // aiding with assertEquals
  data class Show(
    val greeting: String = "Hello"
  ) : State()
}

// ... and possible Events
sealed class Event {
  data class Greet(val name: String) : Event()
}
```

#### With this setup, we can get to the unit testing:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MyViewModelTest {

  val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

  @Test
  fun `viewModel shows initial state`() = runTest {
    val vm = MyViewModel(dispatcher)
    val expectedState = State.Show()

    // Get the initial state
    val state = vm.state

    assertEquals(expectedState, state)
  }

  @Test
  fun `viewModel shows updated state`() = runTest {
    val vm = MyViewModel(dispatcher)
    val expectedState = State.Show("Hello Robertus")

    // Trigger an event
    vm.onEvent(Event.Greet("Robertus"))

    // Await the change
    dispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()

    // Get the state
    val state = vm.state

    assertEquals(expectedState, state)
  }
}
```

The `val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()` lets us pass in a dispatcher we can control for awaiting the coroutine. We pass this to the ViewModel in the tests and when needing to await them to run and update the state.

> Note: the tests are within the expression  `= runTest { }`.

For the first test, `viewModel shows initial state`, we get the initial value the `mutableStatOf` was initialized with.

In the second test, `viewModel shows updated state`, we await the coroutine to complete (dispatcher to idle) by calling `dispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()` between passing the `Event` and getting the `state`.

Without it, we will get the initial state.
[image]

Comment: that means you always have to pass the dispatcher. but in most cases viewModel just calls a repository or UseCase which should be main safe.

Comment: @Carmen you can use Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher) and just use viewModelScope

Comment: Nevertheless with this solution I have to pass a Dispatcher to all my ViewModels :\